# SpringBoot application to send notification via phone numbers on SMS

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring boot - 2.3.3.RELEASE and gradle.

Note- I'm using Factory and Strategy pattern. This project is going to be used as a Library for other projects to import and use the methods exposed by Service layer.

Here is the folder structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQSJf.jpg

**I would appreciate if the community can review this code and give suggestions to make it better.**

Demo.class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
    }
}
```

Init.java

```
@Component
public class InitClass implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    PhoneService phoneService;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        String title="Title";
        String message="message";
        List<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneNumbers.add("333-222-1111");
        phoneService.sendNotificationByPhoneNumbers(title, message, phoneNumbers);
    }
}
```

PhoneService.java

```
@Service
public class PhoneService {

    @Autowired
    PhoneServiceImpl notificationServiceImpl;

    public void sendNotificationByPhoneNumbers(String title, String message, List<String> phoneNumbers) {
        notificationServiceImpl.sendNotificationByPhoneNumbers(title, message, phoneNumbers);
    }
}
```

PhoneServiceImpl.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class PhoneServiceImpl {

    @Value("${notificationService.url}")
    String url;

    public void sendNotificationByPhoneNumbers(String title, String message, List<String> phoneNumbers) {
        PhoneContext phoneContext = new PhoneContext(new SendPhoneByPhoneNumbers(url));
        phoneContext.notify(title, message, phoneNumbers);
    }
}
```

PhoneContext.java

```
public class PhoneContext {

    private PhoneStrategy phoneStrategy;

    public PhoneContext(PhoneStrategy phoneStrategy){
        this.phoneStrategy = phoneStrategy;
    }

    public void notify(String title, String message, List<String> employees){
        phoneStrategy.sendNotification(title, message, employees);
    }
}
```

PhoneStrategy.java

```
public interface PhoneStrategy {

   public void sendNotification(String title, String message, List<String> listOfEmployeeIdGroupNamePhoneNumbers);
}
```

SendPhoneByPhoneNumbers.java

```
@Slf4j
public class SendPhoneByPhoneNumbers implements PhoneStrategy {

    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    String notificationServiceURL;
    BuildHttpRequest buildHttpRequest;

    public SendPhoneByPhoneNumbers(String notificationServiceURL) {
        this.notificationServiceURL = notificationServiceURL;
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        this.buildHttpRequest = new BuildHttpRequest();
    }

    @Async
    public void sendNotification(String title, String message, List<String> listOfEmployeeIdGroupNamePhoneNumbers) {
        SmsMessage smsMessage= new SmsMessage(title, message, listOfEmployeeIdGroupNamePhoneNumbers, Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());

        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set("idToken", buildHttpRequest.getNewToken());

            HttpEntity<SmsMessage> newRequest = new HttpEntity<>(smsMessage, headers);
            restTemplate.postForObject(notificationServiceURL + "/sms/custom", newRequest, String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PhoneService class

In my opinion, the `PhoneService` should be converted to an interface exposing the methods.

```java
public interface PhoneService {
   void sendNotificationByPhoneNumbers(String title, String message, List<String> phoneNumbers);
}
```

Then, the `PhoneServiceImpl` class can implement the interface `PhoneService`.

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PhoneServiceImpl implements PhoneService {

   @Value("${notificationService.url}")
   String url;

   @Override
   public void sendNotificationByPhoneNumbers(String title, String message, List<String> phoneNumbers) {
      PhoneContext phoneContext = new PhoneContext(new SendPhoneByPhoneNumbers(url));
      phoneContext.notify(title, message, phoneNumbers);
   }
}
```

Those’s changes will allow you to use inheritance and make the code easier to refactor if, you want to add any new phone services (new implementations). The old implementation was, in my opinion, a bit confusing and did not add any advantages that I can see.

### Prefer `Constructor-based Dependency Injection` / `Setter-based Dependency Injection` over `Field Injection`

In my opinion, the [`Constructor Dependency Injection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-injection) should be preferred over the `Field Injection` since it makes the testing easier and more natural (you can pass the mocks directly into the constructor) without using hardcore ways to inject the dependencies.

Also, even in Spring documentation, the `Field Injection` [is not even mentioned as a way to inject](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-collaborators) and lots of people don’t recommend it.

### Never expose the variables directly in classes

In my opinion, it's a bad habit to have public variables in classes, since you don’t control your own data. Try to `hide` them by adding the `private` / `protected` keyword before them and use `getters` / `setters` to change the state. This will give you more control over the class own data.